# play audio and video file in GWT

Tags: gwt

i want to play audio and video file using flash player in GWT...how can we integrate that player in GWT...

Answer (score 3):

If you need to communicate between GWT and Flash take a look at [gwt2swf](http://code.google.com/p/gwt2swf/).

If that's not the case and you simply want to create the needed markup you could use the [`HTML`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html) widget.