# How to use GWT to show video, audio and picture?

Tags: flash, gwt, audio, video

I have a GWT project which is not written by me in the beginning and I am lack of knowledge of web development. I want to show video, audio and picture in browsers like ie, chrome.

Can this answer ( [play audio and video file in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181839/play-audio-and-video-file-in-GWT)
 ) solve my problem?

I find [this link](http://code.google.com/p/gwt2swf/wiki/Usage) can't solve my problem because it just tells how to show *.swf file. But the type of my files is various

Comment: Check out https://code.google.com/p/bst-player/

Comment: Thank you ! I find [this tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/bst-player/wiki/GettingStarted) only tell me how to play media in the net.Do you know how to play media from local file system?

Comment: Thank you .I have display the .wma file from local file system .But the container can not be show fully ?

Comment: Hello Mayank Pandya .Would you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606667/bst-player-gwt-media-container-can-not-fully-show) question?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-html5-video/) one to show videos. For  images you can use com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image widget

Comment: Hello Dilantha .Would you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606667/bst-player-gwt-media-container-can-not-fully-show) question?