# bst-player , GWT , media container can not fully show

Tags: gwt, web

[this](https://code.google.com/p/bst-player/downloads/list) is the tool I use to show video and audio .
I use the bst-player-api-2.0.3.jar and core-player-provider-2.0.jar

[this](https://code.google.com/p/bst-player/wiki/GettingStarted) is the code I use .

It shows like this (after added into the parent panel,and it could play sound):

[image]

I have try these code :

```
player.setSize("100%", "100%");
panel.setHeight("1000px");
player.setSize("300px", "300px");
```

I also try:(the whole code)

```
   SimplePanel panel = new SimplePanel();
    panel.setSize("1000px", "1000px");
    AbstractMediaPlayer player = null;
        try {
            player = new WinMediaPlayer("C:/Documents and Settings/dell/Application Data/Tencent/QQMusic/Cache/WhirlCache/转身之间.mp3", true, "300px", "400px");
            player.setResizeToVideoSize(true);
            panel.setWidget(player);
        } catch (PluginVersionException e) {
            panel.setWidget(new HTML(
                    ".. some nice message telling the user to download plugin first .."));
        } catch (PluginNotFoundException e) {
            panel.setWidget(new HTML(
                    ".. another nice message telling the user to download plugin.."));
        }

         add(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not solved my [issue](https://code.google.com/p/bst-player/issues/detail?id=70&thanks=70&ts=1373440293#makechanges) , but can I give you direction do all the stuff I done, make sure if you are using WinMediaPlayer to have working *.wma video and correct location location to it, test it with some crawling app ( I used wget ), the size of video widget is changed by changing the panel not the player.

Comment: forget to say,the player can play sound